# How to invoke WMI method with object reference in C#?

Tags: c#, wmi, pass-by-reference

I have received a WMI class specification with two classes:

- One called 'A' with only an array of bytes in it,
- One called 'B' which contains a method called with signature 'DoSomething([in, out] A data)'

From the MOF:

```
class A {
    [read, write] uint8 Buffer[8];
}
class B {
    [read, write, Implemented] void DoSomething([in, out] A Data);
}
```

The idea is that I shall populate some bytes in A's byte array, call `DoSomething` with it, and then I read out the A's byte array again to get my result. The byte buffer basically acts as a communication device.

Given that somebody else have written a provider for class B, how can I make an instance of class A in C# in which the byte buffer can modified by me AND by the provider of `DoSomething`? Is this even possible as the instance I create lives in managed space?

Would it be possible to do in e.g. C++?